# splitting appsettings section of app.config in two parts

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a windows application and its being deployed via click once. My appsettings inside my app.config have several settings. Some settings are deployment specific like the webserver source for the file download etc. It will vary with deployment region. Some settings items are app specific which wont change during deployment.

```
<appSettings >    
   <add key="key1" value="Value111 changable with region" />
   <add key="Key2" value="Value222 changable with region" />

    <add key="key3" value="Value333 NOT changable with region" />
   <add key="Key4" value="Value444 NOT changable with region" />

 </appSettings >
```

Now I need to split my appsettings in two app.config files.
I want to put key1 and key2 in separate config files. How do I do that.

Comment: what do you mean by changeable?  how will they be changed?

Comment: And how/when do you want to make the switch?

Comment: Fiddling with extra configs is not easy. Using Region1Key1 and Region2Key1 in the same file and a little helper method for reading might do the trick just as well.

Comment: The deployment team will be changing the values for key 1 and 2 based on which region they are deploying to. This app is basically a configurator app for some other app. I made many other items configurable so that I dont need to change code for changes in the main app. It can just be configured. But this wont change based on region of deployment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the appSettings [file attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and give each deployment region its file version.

**app.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="regionsettings.config">
      <add key="key1" value="default value" />
      <add key="commonKey" value="common value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**regionsettings.config** (*region 1*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="region 1" />
</appSettings>
```

**regionsettings.config** (*region 2*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="region 2" />
</appSettings>
```

Or do like Henk suggested:

```
<add key="region1.key1" value="region1key1 value" />
<add key="region2.key1" value="region2key1 value" />
```

Comment: I did try this same appraoch. But my key1 is not being rewritten with the new values.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. Are the files in the same directory? Are the config files well-formed?

Comment: Region settings.config wont have the <configuration> node right ?

Comment: Thanks it finally worked. There is one more thing that needs to be added here is : Make sure that the property 'Copy to Output Directory' of regionsettings.config is set to 'Copy always'. It works after that.

Comment: Yes, you'll need that setting for publishing